# How to get the Google Maps directions (route) sharing feature in web application via its Java Script API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am sorry if this question is not fit for this forum.
I want to get the **Google Maps directions (route) sharing feature** into my web application via Google Maps Java Script API same like **Send directions to your phone** on [Gogle Maps Directions](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Bahawalpur,+Punjab,+Pakistan/Lahore,+Punjab,+Pakistan/@30.4614896,71.8760899,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x393b90c46c611ad5:0xfcdf0da8e103f862!2m2!1d71.6833331!2d29.3957215!1m5!1m1!1s0x39190483e58107d9:0xc23abe6ccc7e2462!2m2!1d74.3571581!2d31.5546061?hl=en-US). Is it possible?
I have searched out but not found any information related to google maps route sharing through Java Script API.If it is possible then please suggest some relevant links or data to impalement it.

Thanks-Hashim

Answer (score 2):

At present time this functionality is not available via Google Maps JavaScript API.

I can see a feature request for this in the Google issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826888

It looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task. Anyway, I suggest adding a star in the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.